# JMeter - Comparison of two modes of running a script

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a jmeter script, it has all the resources urls in the script. so if I put Parallel Controller with 6 connection and run the script, the script reports higher response time THAN if I put only main html URL and check download embedded resouces with 6 parallel connection. ..so why it reports higher response time with Parallel Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Given both approaches execute the same requests you should be getting the same or at least similar results. If you see differences - capture the traffic from both runs using a 3rd-party tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and compare the network footprint for both cases.

I can only think of one possible reason for difference: [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching). If you have [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager/) in your test plan then JMeter respects [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers and doesn't re-request the content on subsequent calls/iterations.

Comment: I do have cache manager in place but still the difference exists.